# What is the difference between Statistical Signal Processing and Estimation and Detection?

Tags: signal-detection, estimation, statistics

Looking at the syllabus of *Statistical Signal Processing* in different university I see a lot of correlation with that of *Estimation and Detection*? In some universities, these are seen the same. For example

- Rice ELEC 531: [Statistical Signal Processing](http://elec531.rice.edu/)
- MIT 6.432: [Stochastic Processes, Detection, and Estimation](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-432-stochastic-processes-detection-and-estimation-spring-2004/)

Now, I'm confused if these two courses are separate courses or can be seen the same. It seems Estimation and Detection is a more specific and/or old naming for Statistical Signal Processing. Is this correct? Do you know of any university offering both of them? If so, what are the differences?

Comment: Although these terms have precise meaning, in practice they are used somewhat interchangably. Do not give too much weight to a course name; you have to look at the details to be sure what it is about.

Comment: It's quite relevant. But what if both courses are offered in one department? What would be the main difference?

Comment: My bet would be that a course like ELEC 531 is less focused on theory than MIT 6.432. But the only way to be sure is to look at the syllabus or, failing that, the required textbooks.